# Store only new data to localStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I want to save some `URLs` in `localStorage` when I scroll through some articles. So far with the code I writed I managed to do that, except that when I came across to same articles I already view, it saves again their url, thus occupying space storage for nothing.

Here's my code:

```
var i = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('names')) {
    var data = [];
  } else {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'));
  }
  var x = $("article");
  var url = x.eq(i).attr("data-entry-url");
  data.push(url);

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= x.eq(i).offset().top && url !== data) {

    localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);

    i++;
  }
});
```

I set the `if url !== data` condition there to check if the specific article URL is already set in `localStorage`to stop adding again, but is not working. How else should I check that?

Comment: try data.indexOf(url) to determine of the url is in data.  [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Tried now `data.indexOf(url)` . Not working either..

Answer (score 0):

The `url` is string type and `data` is array type will never true when you compare. So you have to follow through `if(url == data[0])` if you compare with single url OR if you check with all of the urls in data array follow as `if(data.indexOf(url) >= 0)`.
Try it.

Answer (score 0):

data is an array so we need to use javascript `filter` function to loop in array and then compare it with the url.
Please let me know if you need any more clarification of sample code